# Is it possible to use a URL format "https://[something]/[Tag]" to generate lists of contacts or activities using that Tag?

Tags: searchkit, search-results, tags, custom-search, formbuilder

SearchKit and FormBuilder are a fantastic couple and I'm creating various reports and dashlets for my CRM colleagues. I have a display showing all tags sorted by the amount of times they are used in contacts and activities. I would like to make the tags clickable and pointing to a page listing the contacts or the activities using that tag. It is possible to create these links using "https://[something]" + "Tag" but I can't find that [something].

Is it possible to construct these URLs with SearchKit or CiviCRM's older search engines? Or is there a different way to resolve this problem? Finding pages using a tag is a relatively common use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with SearchKit + FormBuilder.

1. Create a search for Contacts
2. Add it to a form
3. Add "Contact Tags" as a form filter:
   [image: Tags filter]
4. Give your form a title and a url (e.g. `civicrm/contacts-by-tag`) and save.
5. Now visit your form e.g. at `http://example.org/civicrm/contacts-by-tag#?tags=4` and FormBuilder will automatically set the title and show you contacts with that tag:
   [image: Find contacts by tag]
6. In your original search, construct a link to the new form using a token for tag id.

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed the steps above and it works. 

(((I hope this tag navigation will make it to Civi core one day and make the tags in contact cards clickable. So that Civi tags behave like tags in Drupal, Wordpress, etc.)))